# What is the order and structure of Aut(SL$_2(p)$)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, automorphism-group, groups-of-lie-type

Here $p$ is a prime. We know that for $Z(SL_2(p)) = \{ \pm I \}$ and $\lvert SL_2(p)\rvert= p^3-p$ so there are $\frac{p^3-p}{2}$ inner automorphisms. What is the outer automorphism group?

Comment: $PGL_2(p)$ gives a subgroup of the automorphism group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is $\mathrm{PGL}_2(p)$ for $p\geq 5$, which I assume you are thinking about. Any automorphism of $\mathrm{SL}_2(p)$ induces an automorphism on $\mathrm{PSL}_2(p)$. The automorphism group of $\mathrm{PSL}_2(p)$ is $\mathrm{PGL}_2(p)$. The only question is whether one can pull these back to automorphisms of $\mathrm{SL}_2(p)$. You can, and the group $\mathrm{SL}_2(p).2$ is in fact a subgroup of $\mathrm{SL}_2(p^2)$.

Comment: An interesting consequence (which is not true in larger dimensions) is that transpose-inverse (an obvious automorphism) thus is obtained through conjugation by a matrix.

Comment: What about $\text{Aut}(\text{SL}_2(q))$ for a general prime power $q$? It also induces an automorphism on $\text{PSL}_2(q)$ and I can find this group on Wikipedia, but can we pull these back to $\text{SL}_2(q)$?

Comment: Certainly not in general. There is always a group $2\cdot \mathrm{PGL}_2(q)$, but one cannot in general extend the other groups. For example, for $q=9$, two of the three lift to $\mathrm{SL}_2(9)$ (the $S_6$ and $\mathrm{PGL}_2(9)$ ones), but not the third (the $M_{10}$ one).